# Access the returned values of dynamically created Shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking to build a shiny app that dynamically creates modules (via callmodule) that returns a simple form. I have 2 loose ends on it that I would appreciate some guidance on please.

Firstly, when multiple forms are brought to the user (via a button click), the values on previously rendered forms revert to the default. How do I stop this behaviour so that values stay on the users selection?

And 2, how do I access and present ‘all’ the values from the selections into a single tibble that can be shown in a tableOutput?
I have put a simple example together below using observeEvent; I also tried a variation with eventReactive however I just can’t seem to access the callmodule outputs.

Thnx in advance!

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)


gen_r_8_formUI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(fluidRow(column(width = 4, selectInput(ns("slt_forename"), 'forename', choices = unique(c("john", "paul", "george", "ringo")))),
          column(width = 4, selectInput(ns("slt_surname") , 'surname' , choices = unique(c("lennon", "mccartney", "harrison", "starr"))))))
}

gen_r_8_form <- function(input, output, session){

  select_values <- reactiveValues(forename = NULL, surname = NULL)  
  observeEvent(input$slt_forename,{select_values$forename <- input$slt_forename})
  observeEvent(input$slt_surname, {select_values$surname  <- input$slt_surname})
  select_values_all <- reactive({tibble(forename  = select_values$forename, surname  = select_values$surname)})
  
  return(list(select_values_all = reactive({select_values_all()})))
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(width = 2, actionButton("btn_gen_r_8_form", "GEN R 8 a FORM")),
  column(width = 6, uiOutput("all_ui_forms")),
  column(width = 4, tableOutput("all_form_values_table")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rctv_uis                     <- reactiveValues(all_ui          = list())
  gen_forms                    <- reactiveValues(all_form_values = list())
  output$all_ui_forms          <- renderUI({tagList(rctv_uis$all_ui)})
  output$all_form_values_table <- renderTable({all_form_values_rctv()})
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_gen_r_8_form, {
    
    x_id  <- paste( "ns_", str_replace_all(paste(Sys.time()), "-| |:", '') , sep = '')
    gen_forms$all_form_values[[x_id]] <- callModule(module = gen_r_8_form, id = x_id)
    rctv_uis$all_ui[[x_id]] <- gen_r_8_formUI(id = x_id)

  })
  
  
  all_form_values_rctv <- reactive({
    
    # Question - how to make a tibble with all form values?
    
    # tibble(
    #   forenames = 'all gen_forms$all_form_values forenames',
    #   surnames  = 'all gen_forms$all_form_values surnames'
    # )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `insertUI`. It has the advantage that existing UI elements stay the same (no resetting of the previous modules) and only new modules are added. To determine where the UI is added, define a `tags$div(id = "tag_that_determines_the_position")` in the `UI` function. Then, `insertUI` takes this as an argument. Additionally, I've changed a few things:

- simplified the code for the module server function, you basically only need a `reactive`
- use of the new module interface introduced with shiny 1.5.0
- use a bit simpler reactive data structure (less nesting)

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)


gen_r_8_formUI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(fluidRow(column(width = 4, selectInput(ns("slt_forename"), 'forename', choices = unique(c("john", "paul", "george", "ringo")))),
                   column(width = 4, selectInput(ns("slt_surname") , 'surname' , choices = unique(c("lennon", "mccartney", "harrison", "starr"))))))
}

gen_r_8_form <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      select_values_all <- reactive({tibble(forename  = input$slt_forename,
                                            surname  = input$slt_surname)})
      
      return(list(select_values_all = reactive({select_values_all()})))
    }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(width = 2, actionButton("btn_gen_r_8_form", "GEN R 8 a FORM")),
  column(width = 6, tags$div(id = "add_UI_here")),
  column(width = 4, tableOutput("all_form_values_table")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  gen_forms                    <- reactiveValues()
  current_id <- 1
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_gen_r_8_form, {
    x_id <- paste0("module_", current_id)
    
    gen_forms[[x_id]] <- gen_r_8_form(id = x_id)
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_UI_here",
             ui = gen_r_8_formUI(x_id))
    
    current_id <<- current_id + 1
  })
  
  
  all_form_values_rctv <- reactive({
    res <- lapply(reactiveValuesToList(gen_forms), function(current_module_output) {
      current_module_output$select_values_all()
    })
    
    # prevent to show an error message when the first module is added
    if (length(res) != 0 && !is.null(res[[1]]$forename)) {
      dplyr::bind_rows(res)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
    
  })
  
  output$all_form_values_table <- renderTable({
    all_form_values_rctv()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks starja - That's exactly what I was looking for. Interesting to see moduleServer also. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
  all_form_values_rctv <- reactive({
    dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(gen_forms$all_form_values, function(x) {
      x$select_values_all()
    }))
  })
```

You've collected all the model reactive elements in `gen_forms$all_form_values` so you iterate over them and get the reactive value and then bind all those tables together.

Comment: This solution still leads to "resetting" the values of the previous modules, because the UI is generated new everytime `output$all_ui_forms` is updated

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. starja's answer also gave a solution for the form updating issue so I accepted that answer but thanks for the bindrows/lappy angle. Much appreciated.