# Is there a method to using removeUI in for loop?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm dynamically generating inputs using a custom function `render_panels` that creates a `wellPanel` with a `selectizeInput` and `actionButton` contained within, the `actionButton` removes the entire `wellPanel` using `removeUI` by using the id of the div as the selector.  I also have a global add button to add new `wellPanel`.

I have a method to remove the `wellPanel` by observing the remove button event for each panel, then using `removeUI` and specifying corresponding div id as selector, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method to do this with either for loop or vectorized approach.

Edit Note: Instead of `insertUI`, I'm specifically using this approach in order to provide the ability to initialize the app with panels already inserted. The shiny app will be executed as a function where users could provide a character vector of dropdown selection values, for example. I've added a character vector `prevInputs` inside server, a reactive value `counter$n` which has replaced  `input$add` in order to create initial panels of `length(prevInputs)` if `!is.null(prevInputs)` and a method to initialize the `selected` values argument for `selectizeInput` with existing values inside `make_panels` to illustrate the point.

See reprex:

```
library(shiny)


render_panels <- function(n, removed_panels, inputs){
  
  make_panels <- function(n, inputs){
    panels <- tags$div(id = n,
                       wellPanel(
                         selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("dropdown", n), label = paste0("dropdown", n), choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = inputs[[paste0("dropdown", n)]]),
                         actionButton(paste0("remove", n), label = paste0("remove", n))
                       )
    )
  }
  
  ui_out <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
  
  for(i in seq_along(ui_out)){
    if(i %in% removed_panels) next
    ui_out[[i]] <- tagList(
      make_panels(n = i, inputs)
    )
  }
  
  return(ui_out)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           actionButton("add", label = "add"),
           uiOutput("mypanels")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  removed <- reactiveValues(
    values = list()
  )
  
  prevInputs <- c("a", "b", "c")
  
  reactiveInputs <- reactiveValues(values = list())
  
  observe({
    reactiveInputs$values$dropdown1 = prevInputs[[1]]
    reactiveInputs$values$dropdown2 = prevInputs[[2]]
    reactiveInputs$values$dropdown3 = prevInputs[[3]]
  })
  
  
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = ifelse(!is.null(prevInputs), length(prevInputs), 0))
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    counter$n <- counter$n + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove1,{
    removed$values <- c(removed$values, 1)
    removeUI(
      selector =  "div#1",  immediate = TRUE,
    )
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$remove2,{
    removed$values <- c(removed$values, 2)
    removeUI(
      selector =  "div#2",  immediate = TRUE,
    )
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$remove3,{
    removed$values <- c(removed$values, 3)
    removeUI(
      selector =  "div#3",  immediate = TRUE,
    )
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  
  output$mypanels <- renderUI({
    render_panels(n = counter$n, removed_panels = removed$values, inputs = reactiveInputs$values)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, if there are 100 `wellPanels` generated, I'd have to use 100 `observeEvent`, not what we want...here is my attempt at for loop:

I'd like to replace all `observeEvent` calls with something like below, but cannot seem to get things working.

```
observe({
    req(input$remove1)
    for(i in seq_len(input$add)){
      if(input[[paste0("remove", i)]] == 1){
        removeUI(selector = paste0("div#", i), immediate = TRUE)
      }
    }
  })
```

Edit:
Here is an attempt from a provided answer using `shinymaterial` package for alternative UI. Note `shinymaterial` package requires you to wrap ui elements in `render_material_from_server` inside `renderUI` for any UI generated on the server side i.e.

```
output$dropdown <- renderUI({
    render_material_from_server(
        material_dropdown(input_id = paste0("dropdown", n), label = paste0("dropdown", n), choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = "a")
        )
    })
```

This function `render_material_from_server` is newly available and only exists in current development version of package on GH: [shinymaterial](https://github.com/ericrayanderson/shinymaterial)

In any case, `insertUI` does not render UI elements as expected using `material_page` UI of from `shinymaterial`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

make_panels <- function(n, selected){
  tags$div(
    material_card(
      material_dropdown(input_id = paste0("dropdown", n), label = paste0("dropdown", n), choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = selected),
      actionButton(paste0("remove", n), label = paste0("remove", n), class = "mybtn")
    )
  )
}


ui <- material_page(
  tags$script("
        $(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function(){
          $(this).parent().remove();
        })
                "),
  material_row(
    material_column(width = 6,
           actionButton("add", label = "add"),
           uiOutput("mypanels")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  choices = c("a", "b", "c")
  init_counter <- reactiveVal(3)
  
  observe({
    for(i in seq_len(isolate(init_counter()))){
      insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(i, choices[i]))
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    panel_index <- init_counter() + input$add
    insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(panel_index, choices[panel_index]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this situation is a good usecase for [modules](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html). Basically, you only write the code once how to generate a panel and then call this module every time you want a new panel. Inside the module, the `observeEvent` is automatically generated so you don't have to repeat code.

2 things to add:

- if you want to access the data returned by the module, you need to [store the output of the module call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457730/access-the-returned-values-of-dynamically-created-shiny-modules/63458971#63458971) in the main server function
- having a lot of modules generates a lot of observers. These observers also stay when a module ui is removed. See [this blog post](https://appsilon.com/how-to-safely-remove-a-dynamic-shiny-module/) how to deal with this if it should get a problem.

```
library(shiny)

mod_panel_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  panel_number <- regmatches(id,
                             regexpr("[0-9]+", id))
  tags$div(id = id,
           wellPanel(
             selectizeInput(inputId = ns("dropdown"),
                            label = paste0("dropdown ", panel_number),
                            choices = c("a", "b", "c"),
                            selected = NULL),
             actionButton(ns("remove"), label = paste0("remove ", panel_number))
           )
  )
}

mod_panel <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 observeEvent(input$remove, {
                   removeUI(selector = paste0("div#", id))
                 })
               })
  
  return(list(
    dropdown = reactive(input$dropdown)
  ))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           actionButton("add", label = "add"),
           div(id = "add_panels_here")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  counter_panels <- 1
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    current_id <- paste0("panel_", counter_panels)
    mod_panel(current_id)
    insertUI(selector = "#add_panels_here",
             ui = mod_panel_ui(current_id))
    
    # update counter
    counter_panels <<- counter_panels + 1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Edit

Here is a solution that uses `shinymaterial` and already shows 2 panels on startup. The selected element can be specified by an additional argument to the module server function:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

mod_panel_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("placeholder"))
}

mod_panel <- function(id, selection = NULL) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 # generate the UI on the server side
                 ns <- session$ns
                 panel_number <- regmatches(id,
                                            regexpr("[0-9]+", id))
                 output$placeholder <- renderUI({render_material_from_server(tags$div(id = id,
                                                          material_card(
                                                            material_dropdown(input_id = ns("dropdown"),
                                                                              label = paste0("dropdown ", panel_number),
                                                                              choices = c("a", "b", "c"),
                                                                              selected = selection),
                                                            actionButton(ns("remove"), label = paste0("remove ", panel_number))
                                                          )
                 ))
                 })
                 
                 # remove the element
                 observeEvent(input$remove, {
                   removeUI(selector = paste0("div#", id))
                 })
               })
  
  return(list(
    dropdown = reactive(input$dropdown)
  ))
}

ui <- material_page(
  material_row(
    material_column(width = 6,
                    actionButton("add", label = "add"),
                    div(id = "add_panels_here")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  counter_panels <- 1
  panels_on_startup <- 2
  selected_on_startup <- c("b", "c")
  
  # add counters on startup
  lapply(seq_len(panels_on_startup), function(i) {
    current_id <- paste0("panel_", counter_panels)
    mod_panel(current_id, selected_on_startup[i])
    insertUI(selector = "#add_panels_here",
             ui = mod_panel_ui(current_id))
    
    # update counter
    counter_panels <<- counter_panels + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    current_id <- paste0("panel_", counter_panels)
    mod_panel(current_id)
    insertUI(selector = "#add_panels_here",
             ui = mod_panel_ui(current_id))
    
    # update counter
    counter_panels <<- counter_panels + 1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and your illustration of how modules can provide a solution here. One of the reasons I used my approach is to allow the user to initialize the app with panels already generated (shiny app will be launched as a function, and user may provide a character vector as an argument to the function in order initialize n `selectizeInput` upon app startup without depending on `observeEvent(input$add,{`  I am not sure if this could be done with your module approach? I've updated original post with edit note and updated reprex. Thank you again for the thorough response.

Comment: See my edit. You can generate non-reactive code in the `server` function which is only executed once on startup

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using your approach, how could one initialize the selections of the first two panels created on startup with values already defined i.e. if we have `panel_vals <- c("b", "c")` in server, I want to initialize dropdown 1 selection with "b" and dropdown 2 selection with "c"

Comment: you can pass additional arguments to the module server function; see my edited code

Comment: Thank you for helping me work through this! One note, the initial panels do render as expected, however, adding new panels created an issue. I was able to resolve this by wrapping all ui elements inside `render_material_from_server()` in the `mod_panel` function i.e.` renderUI({render_material_from_server(...)})`

Comment: thank you for the note, I've edited the code to include it. If you find the answer helpful, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to do so if you know some javascript.

- There is no need to use for loop
- There is no need to save things in a list.
- There is no need for `renderUI`
- There is no need to observe every panel

All you need to do is add a js listener to the remove button and add a class in R `class = "mybtn"` for js to listen to.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

In your server, you need to think the reverse way, using `insertUI` rather than `removeUI`. You only need one observer for the `add` button. When every time you click on `add`, add a panel to a div. In my case, I'm lazy, so I just directly select your `uiOutput("mypanels")`

```r
library(shiny)
make_panels <- function(n){
    tags$div(
        wellPanel(
            selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("dropdown", n), label = paste0("dropdown", n), choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = NULL),
            actionButton(paste0("remove", n), label = paste0("remove", n), class = "mybtn")
        )
    )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script("
        $(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function(){
          $(this).parent().remove();
        })
                "),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 6,
               actionButton("add", label = "add"),
               uiOutput("mypanels")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(input$add))
    })
    observe({
        print(input$dropdown5)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To make sure this works, I add a test observer to watch the `dropdown5` (the dropdown when you add the 5th panel). You will see the dropdown value in console once you add the 5th panel.

**EDIT** for your note:

You can still insert with preset panels. Add a reactive counter for how many panels you want to initiate. Just make sure you `isolate` the counter and the `choice` if that is reactive too. In my example `choice` is hard-coded so I didn't isolate. This is to prevent the panel initialization been run later. The observe I added will only run once.

I also use `[]` instead of `[[]]` which gives `NA` instead of error when out of boundary.

```r
library(shiny)
make_panels <- function(n, selected){
    tags$div(
        wellPanel(
            selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("dropdown", n), label = paste0("dropdown", n), choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = selected),
            actionButton(paste0("remove", n), label = paste0("remove", n), class = "mybtn")
        )
    )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$script("
        $(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function(){
          $(this).parent().remove();
        })
                "),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 6,
               actionButton("add", label = "add"),
               uiOutput("mypanels")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    choices = c("a", "b", "c")
    init_counter <- reactiveVal(3)
    observe({
        for(i in seq_len(isolate(init_counter()))){
            insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(i, choices[i]))
        }
    })
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        panel_index <- init_counter() + input$add
        insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(panel_index, choices[panel_index]))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### To work with materialUI:

change the `tags$script()` to this one

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

make_panels <- function(n, selected){
    tags$div(
        material_card(
            material_dropdown(input_id = paste0("dropdown", n), label = paste0("dropdown", n), choices = c("a", "b", "c"), selected = selected),
            actionButton(paste0("remove", n), label = paste0("remove", n), class = "mybtn")
        )
    )
}


ui <- material_page(
    HTML("<script>
        $(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function(){
          $(this).parent().remove();
        })
        var formatDropdown = function() {
            function initShinyMaterialDropdown(callback) {
                $('.shiny-material-dropdown').formSelect();
                callback();
            }
    
            initShinyMaterialDropdown(function() {
    
            var shinyMaterialDropdown = new Shiny.InputBinding();
            $.extend(shinyMaterialDropdown, {
              find: function(scope) {
                return $(scope).find('select.shiny-material-dropdown');
              },
              getValue: function(el) {
                var ans;
                ans = $(el).val();
                if (ans === null) {
                  return ans;
                }
                if (typeof(ans) == 'string') {
                  return ans.replace(new RegExp('_shinymaterialdropdownspace_', 'g'), ' ');
                } else if (typeof(ans) == 'object') {
                  for (i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof(ans[i]) == 'string') {
                      ans[i] = ans[i].replace(new RegExp('_shinymaterialdropdownspace_', 'g'), ' ');
                    }
                  }
                  return ans;
                } else {
                  return ans;
                }
              },
              subscribe: function(el, callback) {
                $(el).on('change.shiny-material-dropdown', function(e) {
                  callback();
                });
              },
              unsubscribe: function(el) {
                $(el).off('.shiny-material-dropdown');
              }
            });
    
            Shiny.inputBindings.register(shinyMaterialDropdown);
            });
            }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(formatDropdown, 500);
        })
        $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
            setTimeout(formatDropdown, 100);
        })
</script>"),
    material_row(
        material_column(width = 6,
                        actionButton("add", label = "add"),
                        uiOutput("mypanels")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    choices = c("a", "b", "c")
    init_counter <- reactiveVal(3)
    
    observe({
        for(i in seq_len(isolate(init_counter()))){
            insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(i, choices[i]))
        }
    })
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        panel_index <- init_counter() + input$add
        insertUI(selector = "#mypanels", where = "beforeEnd", ui = make_panels(panel_index, choices[panel_index]))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I neglected to use insertUI for some functionality that is needed to initialize the app with panels already generated. I don't think this could be achieved with insertUI if I am correct? I've updated reprex and provided edit note.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example, for the actual shiny app I'm working on I've been using material design components from the `shinymaterial` package and have always faced UI generation issues with `insertUI`. I didn't want to have to complicate things further and tried to illustrate the issue I faced using `shiny` ui components, but it seems like `shinymaterial` and `insertUI` don't seem to jive well together. I've provided an attempt with `shinymaterial` using your solution in the original post.

Comment: I appreciate the updated script. We're almost there, but as you can see, when changing `fluidPage` to  `material_page` and `selectizeInput` to `material_dropdown`, the `material_dropdown` does not render as expected.

Comment: The functionality of the remove button also appears to be broken now.

Comment: That is the problem with your computer and browser. I tested with windows and linux. All worked perfectly.